# Azure functions HttpTrigger 404 shows as success in Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions with dotnet 6 in a isolated process. I noticed that any http status code in the 400 range will be marked as a success in Application Insights. I have out of the box setup for AI. Is there any configuration that will mark 400 level status as a failed response?

Answer (score 0):

> 400 range will be marked as a success in Application Insights

From the Point of View of Function App runtime, the request will be processed successfully without errors but not the operation/functionality of the function is a success. So, it makes sense that the Function App registers the call as success in Application Insights too.

We didn't want to use status codes to guess whether there was a successful operation or not, so we look for whether the function threw an exception.

As You didn't post any screenshot of exception details, If you go to App Insights Analytics and query for that  `ExceptionTelemetry`, you should see it.

In order to correlate it with a specific function, you'd need to set the  `OperationId`, (same as the function's  `InvocationId`). There is a sample that shows how to do this with Events, Metrics, and Dependencies, but doing it for Exceptions is the same (you can ignore the  `User.Id`  assignment): [Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions)